Universal Nets: Puzzled regarding an apparent contradiction
In the chapter on nets in Bredon's Topology and Geometry, there is a theorem that every net has a universal subnet.  There is also an exercise that asks you to prove that a sequence is a universal net if and only if it is eventually constant.  These two statements seem to imply that every sequence has a subnet (subsequence) that is eventually constant, which appears to be trivially false (consider, for example, the sequence x_n = n).  Where am I going wrong?

A subnet of a sequence is not necessarily a sequence

What is a universal subnet?

A net is universal if for any subset of the ambient space, the net is eventually contained in either that subset or its complement. It gives a neat characterization of compactness: a space is compact if and only if every universal net converges.
